# ASP.NET Core : modify headers in middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, middleware

**Scenario 1**

I have a custom middleware in my .NET 6 project. The invoke method looks like this:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("testing1", "someValue1"); // good

    await _next(context);

    context.Response.Headers.Add("testing2", "someValue2"); // line 1 - bad
}
```

Here line 1 will fail with this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.

However, if I do this, it allows me to modify the headers:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("testing1", "someValue1");  // good

    await _next(context);

    if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Location"))  // if I redirect
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("testing2", "someValue2");  // line 1 - good
    }
}
```

I can hit line 1 if I do a simple redirect in my controller, such as:

```
return RedirectToAction("Get", "WeatherForecast");
```

and then it allows me to set the headers when I reach line 1 in my middleware.

**Scenario 2**

This time, the same middleware is trying to modify response body:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("testing1", "someValue1");

    await _next(context);

    var data = new
    {
        x = 1,
        y = 2,
        s = "s1",
        arr1 = new List<int> { 11, 111, 1111 },
        arr2 = new List<string> { "s22", "s222", "s2222" },
    };
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;                           // line 1 - fail
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(json, Encoding.UTF8);
 }
```

Line 1 fails, the exception is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.

Likewise, if it is a redirect, it will pass through:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("testing1", "someValue1");

    await _next(context);

    if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Location"))
    {
        var data = new
        {
            x = 1,
            y = 2,
            s = "s1",
            arr1 = new List<int> { 11, 111, 1111 },
            arr2 = new List<string> { "s22", "s222", "s2222" },
        };
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;                      // line 1 - good
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(json, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Line 1 is good now, data is returned correctly to the client app.

I am new to .NET 6, can someone shed some light to my questions:

1. Why are you not allowed to modify response headers or body AFTER `await _next(context)`? Isn't it the purpose of middleware, to let you modify http context coming in and going out of your middleware pipeline?
2. Why a redirect check would suddenly allow you to modify the response headers and body? What is the magic behind that?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Tammy Leung, I have do research for the source code and find the code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d40eea990edd1ac7205a983cbe4d13a71fd4ad68/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/ResponseFeature.cs#L105) it sets the header readonly if the response is already returning.